# Deleting non used objects in operator= overloading

Tags: c++

Let's say that I have a class A:

```
class A
{
    private:
    int value;
    public:
    A(int value)
    {
        this->value=value;
    }
    A& operator= (A& obj)
    {
        value=obj.value;
    }
};
```

There is a problem if I use the contextual instantiation:

```
A obj;
obj=*new A(5);
```

This case the new object created is not deleted and I lose it's reference.
So I could put in the operator= overloading function the instruction to delete the object which is right value of the assignment, but if I do this:

```
A obj1,obj2;
obj1=obj2;
```

So how to avoid to waste memory? There's a way?

@Oli Charlesworth :
But then how are iterators implemented? For example in std::list if I say:

```
list<string> l;
// initialize the list elements
list<string>::iterator i=l.begin();
```

This is an assignment, is another object of kind list::iterator created?

Comment: Yes, you're making a copy of `list<string>::iterator`. Iterators are designed to be copyable. If you want to learn more about how objects are created and destroyed, you can pick up [a good C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: So the object created by l.begin() is lost?

Answer (score 7):

Yes, the solution is to not do `obj = *new A(5)`.  Just do `obj = A(5)`.

---

<sub>BTW, your copy-assignment operator should take its argument as a `const` ref.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

It is a terrible idea to do:

```
obj=*new A(5);
```

which does not allow you to destroy the reference `new A(5)` anymore. Instead, initialize directly or by the assignment operator `A& operator= (const A& other)`:

```
A obj(5);

A obj;
obj = A(5);
```

You should definitely learn about the ["Rule of three"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C++_programming%29) so that you won't end up with memory problems.

Comment: I'm not sure that's relevant here.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: Edited my answer to make it more clear. Regarding the OP's edit, I assume he doesn't know how copy constructors etc. work.